# menu that slides over view controller SWIFT

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, presentmodalviewcontroller

I am kinda new to swift and trying to implement a touch menu. So far i connected the view controllers and have the menu working fine with this code the problem i am having i don’t want it to push down the other view controller. I want it to appear over it. The code below pushes everything down. How do i modify it to appear over the view controller instead of pushing.

```
import UIKit

@objc protocol MenuTransitionManagerDelegate {
    func dismiss()
}

class MenuTransitionManager: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning, UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {

    let duration = 0.5
    var isPresenting = false

    var snapshot:UIView? {
        didSet {
            if let delegate = delegate {
                let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: delegate, action: "dismiss")
                snapshot?.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
            }
        }
    }

    var delegate:MenuTransitionManagerDelegate?

    func transitionDuration(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> NSTimeInterval {
        return duration
    }

    func animateTransition(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
        // Get reference to our fromView, toView and the container view
        let fromView = transitionContext.viewForKey(UITransitionContextFromViewKey)!
        let toView = transitionContext.viewForKey(UITransitionContextToViewKey)!

        // Set up the transform we'll use in the animation
        guard let container = transitionContext.containerView() else {
            return
        }

        let moveDown = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, container.frame.height - 240)
        let moveUp = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -50)

        // Add both views to the container view
        if isPresenting {
            toView.transform = moveUp
            snapshot = fromView.snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates(true)
            container.addSubview(toView)
            container.addSubview(snapshot!)
        }

        // Perform the animation
        UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0.8, options: [], animations: {

            if self.isPresenting {
                self.snapshot?.transform = moveDown
                toView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
            } else {
                self.snapshot?.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
                fromView.transform = moveUp
            }

            }, completion: { finished in

                transitionContext.completeTransition(true)

                if !self.isPresenting {
                    self.snapshot?.removeFromSuperview()
                }
        })
    }

    func animationControllerForPresentedController(presented: UIViewController, presentingController presenting: UIViewController, sourceController source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {

        isPresenting = true
        return self
    }

    func animationControllerForDismissedController(dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {

        isPresenting = false
        return self
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify this line.

```
let moveDown = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, container.frame.height - 240)
let moveUp = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -50)
```

Those line basically change the frame of view controller that is being presented/dismissed. If you want the new view controller like its appear above the current view controller, try change its alpha properties.

if you are going to change its alpha, here is the example to get you the basic idea.

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(1, animations: {
  fromView.alpha = 0.3
  toView.alpha = 1
})
```

Comment: Alpha properties what u mean?

Comment: Alpha properties from UIView is floating point number that represents its transparency. you can read more from [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/alpha).

Answer (score 0):

I take a different approach.
In Storyboard/Document Outline, make sure your menu View follows your normal view so it is on top.

Add constraints for the Menu View.

Next, set in size inspector, set the constraints such that the menu sits above the view (ie. out of the visible window).

Cntl-Drag from the top and bottom constraints to the VC to create outlets for them.

Then animate the change of constraint values top constraint to 0 and the bottom constraint to:

```
frame.size.height - menuheight
```

(code or compute as appropriate)

Hiding it, change the top constraint to:

```
menuHeight * -1
```

and bottom constraint to:

```
frame.size.height
```

Left and right constraints can, obviously stay put.

Consider: if you have a status bar and or Nav Bar you might need to factor in an extra 20; 44 to the equation - i.e. menu showing top constraint would then be 64, etc.